# Resolution to assign to the bug when reopened not working on mantisbt

Tags: mantis

the default in `config_defaults_inc.php` suggests that any reopened bug/issue in Mantis gets given the resolution `REOPENED`, i've changed this in the file to `OPEN`  but this seems to have no affect when reopening a closed bug/issue.

We have a button on our bug/issues that allow for a previously closed issue to be reopened Status changed from closed to acknowledge, however our resolution field keeps the previous value (in our case `fixed` but we would like it to be `open`

the function in `html_api.php` for this button is

`function html_button_bug_reopen( $p_bug_id ) {
    $t_status = bug_get_field( $p_bug_id, 'status' );
    $t_project = bug_get_field( $p_bug_id, 'project_id' );
    $t_reopen_status = config_get( 'bug_reopen_status', null, null, $t_project );

```
if( access_has_bug_level( config_get( 'reopen_bug_threshold', null, null, $t_project ), $p_bug_id ) ||
(( bug_get_field( $p_bug_id, 'reporter_id' ) == auth_get_current_user_id() ) && ( ON == config_get( 'allow_reporter_reopen', null, null, $t_project ) ) ) ) {
    html_button( 'bug_change_status_page.php', lang_get( 'reopen_bug_button' ), 
    array( 'id' => $p_bug_id, 'new_status' => $t_reopen_status, 'reopen_flag' => ON ) );
}
```

}
`

adding  `'resolution' => '10',` to the array (10 being the value for Open) doesn't do anything.
Is this a bug with mantisBT or does anyone know how to make this possible, ideally without editing the core files.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out the resolution flag is changed automatically on another version on mantisBT i have installed. just not this one for some reason.

so will close this as the answer.